# Method to get the max sum between values in a list that's no overcomes another integer thats user gave in python?

Tags: python

i want to do a function which takes as a input a list of distances and a positive integer. The function returns the largest sum of the elements in the list so that it does not exceed the integer that has passed as the second argument.

I tried this, but losing prices:

```
def maxDistance(dis,x):
    max=0
    flag="True"
    if sum(dis) <= x :
        return sum(dis)
    for i in range(len(dis)):
        if dis[i] == x:
            return dis[i]
            break
        if dis[i] < x:
            flag="False"
        if dis[i] > max and dis[i] < x:
            max = dis[i]
        for j in range(i+1,len(dis)):
            if dis[i]+dis[j] > max and dis[i]+dis[j] <= x:
                max = dis[i]+dis[j]
    if flag == "True":
        return "Your integer is smaller than your list"
    else:
        return max
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "Losing prices" doesn't help us, as there are no "prices" in your code ... which doesn't execute.

Comment: i want to do a function which takes as a input a list of distances and a positive integer. The function returns the largest sum of the elements in the list so that it does not exceed the integer that has passed as the second argument.

Comment: sum of two elements or more than two?

Comment: @StefanosGregory: you need to give us an example of the problem.  Provide `dis`, `x`, and trace the problematic output for us.

Comment: Is this not the knapsack problem?

Comment: Again, provide a MCVE, *not* your entire function.

Comment: maybe is two or three or four depends on the integer that will give us the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your list be `l1`  and the second arg as limit be `a1` then:-

```
>>> l1 = [1,4,6,10]
>>> a1 = 9
>>> from  itertools import combinations as comb
>>> 
>>> v1 = list(comb(l1,2))  # making list of combinations of 2-2 elements of list l1
>>> 
>>> def max1(dis, x):
...     var = 0
...     for i in dis:
...         if sum(i) <= x and sum(i) >= var: var = sum(i) # doing comparision
...     return var
... 
>>> max1(v1, a1)   # this will give the intended output.
7
```